# Would it be a big security vulnerability if someone wrote a browser extension to retrieve personal information on Google's behalf?

Tags: web-application, malware, browser-extensions, google-apps

I am a 6th grader working in a project and came across the following question:

On most browsers, you can inject JavaScript code into the browser, for example by typing in javascript:alert('Injecting javascript code'). On Google Chrome, if you do this on Google Drive, instead of the title being "drive.google.com says", the title is "Google Drive". Would this be a security threat in any way if someone wrote a malicious extension to ask for personal information on Google's behalf?

Comment: Was this question a part of your project? Or did you think of it separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a security vulnerability, yes.

Executing javascript code in the context of a web page allows that code more or less full access to the content of the page, in this case Google Drive. Such code could leak content, and ask for information such as passwords.

This is generally referred to as [Cross site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or XSS in shorthand.

The specific case of making the user enter the code is called [Self XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS). Sites such as facebook warn against it if you bring up the console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in chrome:

[image]